# Reading packets with Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, sniffing, packet

How do I read packets captured with Wireshark. I was finally able to capture incoming and outgoing data in hopes of developing something along the lines of an IDS. Thanks in advance for the help. A simple point in the right direction would be nice.
[image]

Comment: [Chapter 6. Working with captured packets](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChapterWork.html) and [3.13. The “Tools” menu](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUseToolsMenuSection.html#ChUseTools) also search for "How do I create firewall rules from packets captured with Wireshark"

Comment: I was asking how to read the hex dump information.

Comment: See the first link "You can then expand any part of the tree to view detailed information about each protocol in each packet. Clicking on an item in the tree will highlight the corresponding bytes in the byte view. "